# How to conditionally set a model in asp.net MVC view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am a beginner in ASP.NET MVC.
My page has one partial view called _Navigation that I am reusing.
If the user is in the "Home" the `<a>` of the navigation needs to point to the "#" char, if the user is in the "Services" page, the href of the navigation needs to point to other url, let's say "www.mysite.com". It will occur with other links in this menu too.

I tried to do the following

```
@if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsValue("Services"))
{
    @model MySite.Models.ServicesNavigation
}
else
{
    @model MySite.Models.HomeNavigation
}
```

But it says I can have only one model.
How to solve it?

Comment: i am asking for a "model based" solution, but as a beginner, i dont know if this is the best way to solve this problem, any suggestions will welcome.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687061/Multiple-Models-in-a-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-MVC)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `Interface`.

```
public interface INavigation
{
    //Your props here
}

public class ServicesNavigation : INavigation
{
}

public class HomeNavigation: INavigation
{
}
```

Then your view can be of type INavigation.

```
@model INavigation
```

And in your controller based on your conditions you can pass the impementation of `INavigation` you want.

```
.......
INavigation model;
if(conditionOneIsMet)
{
    model = new ServicesNavigation();    
}
else
{
    model = new HomeNavigation();
}

return View(model);
```

Comment: Worked well. It's an elegant and efficient solution. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your view is in fact a class derived from the `WebViewPage<TModel>` class. The `@model` statement defines type of the model (`TModel`) Because it is the compile time statement, you can't change it in run time.

If you need two different models, you should have two different views.

Comment: It is possible (or good practice) to conditionally (if is the Service Controller) set variables (view bag or view data) in the controller? For example, in the Service controller i set the URLs for the service menu and in the home menu i set the URLs for the home menu?

Comment: Yes, of course. It is possible and a controller is the best place to do it.