# ASP.Net MVC return partial view based on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

this is probably a pretty dumb question, but I'm new to MVC, and I just don't know how to do this.  I need to return different views based on a variable status.  When I try to return partial views inside of a conditional statement, the method gives the error that no value is returned.  Here's an idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
if (status == 1)
{
    return PartialView("partial1", model);
}
if (status == 2)
{
   return PartialView("partial2", model);
}
if (status == 3)
{
    return PartialView("partial3", model);
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean `if (status == 1)`

Comment: Post your entire controller action (after fixing the code, look at @StephenMueckes' comment), and the exact error message.

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry about that.  I was just trying to type out a simple sample.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33981693/2037335) might help

Comment: @ataravati I can't post the entire controller.  I got in trouble today with my boss for posting proprietary.  The error message I'm getting is not all code paths return a value.

Comment: Hard to say without the full code of the method, but you do need an `else` or  a final return statement. What if your function is called without `status` equal to 1, 2 or 3?

Comment: @Khalos that was the answer.  Post as an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: "the error" - I don't see how partial code you have can produce an error... so [MCVE] would be nice. Based on accepted answer code in question has almost nothing to do with error you see... and you should have found tons of duplicates if searched for "the error" message.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm new to this.  I'm sorry my question offended you.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I totally agree, that's why I voted for this question to be closed. It won't help anyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an else or a final return statement.

What if your function is called without status equal to 1, 2 or 3?

For example, assume `status = 4`:

```
public ActionResult SomeMethod(int status) //Assume 4 is passed in
{
    if (status == 1)
    {
        return PartialView("partial1", model);
    }
    if (status == 2)
    {
       return PartialView("partial2", model);
    }
    if (status == 3)
    {
        return PartialView("partial3", model);
    }

    //We got here, but haven't returned anything!
}
```

We need the function to return *something*. I'm not sure what makes the most sense for your application, but something like this is needed.

```
public ActionResult SomeMethod(int status) //Assume 4 is passed in
{
    if (status == 1)
    {
        return PartialView("partial1", model);
    }
    if (status == 2)
    {
       return PartialView("partial2", model);
    }
    if (status == 3)
    {
        return PartialView("partial3", model);
    }

    //We got here, so return some default or fallback Partial.
    return PartialView("SomeFallbackPartial", model);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may have a design error if one controller action is doing so much, but you can fix your issue in one of these ways...

Add a default:

```
if (status == 1)
{
    return PartialView("partial1", model);
}
if (status == 2)
{
   return PartialView("partial2", model);
}
if (status == 3)
{
    return PartialView("partial3", model);
}

return PartialView("default");
```

Throw an exception:

```
if (status == 1)
{
    return PartialView("partial1", model);
}
if (status == 2)
{
   return PartialView("partial2", model);
}
if (status == 3)
{
    return PartialView("partial3", model);
}

throw new CustomException("Invalid status");
```

As they all share a model, perhaps you could use a map to get the view name based on the status (or concatenate it if it really is the same number as the status).

```
var viewName = string.format("partial{0}", status);
return PartialView(viewName, model);
```